# ¿De dónde proviene la frase "Mal de puerco"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, méxico

Por lo menos en México es de uso común que, después de haber comido, uno tenga la sensación de pesadez, sueño, ganas de no regresar a ninguna actividad ([fuente](http://archivo.eluniversal.com.mx/ciencia/2015/mal-puerco-101031.html)). Por lo general luego de haber comido más de la cuenta.

A este *sentir*, si se le puede llamar así, se le denomina **Mal de puerco**, pero he estado investigando y no sé por qué ni cuándo se empezó a usar dicha frase.

Así que mi pregunta es esa misma, ¿cuándo y por qué se empezó a usar la frase **Mal de puerco**?

Comment: Me permito añadir un enlace para que los que no conozcamos la expresión podamos tener un poco más de contexto. En todo caso, no la encuentro en textos ni en el CREA ni en el CORDE. ¿Te suena que sea de aparición reciente, o se lleva usando mucho tiempo?

Comment: Claro, muchas gracias... pues por lo que he visto, la gente de edad avanzada es quien mas utiliza esta expresión, pero en general es de uso comun

Comment: Publiqué la pregunta [en Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/5rgavv/de_d%C3%B3nde_proviene_la_frase_mal_de_puerco/) y están saliendo comentarios muy esclarecedores. Le doy un poco más de tiempo y luego los recopilo.

Comment: enterado, espero lo que hayas podido encontrar

Answer (score 2):

Veamos la [definición de *mal de puerco*](http://www.sdpnoticias.com/columnas/2013/11/12/te-ha-dado-el-mal-del-puerco):

> El mal del puerco es cuando sientes esa sensación de dormir exactamente después de comer, te sientes sin ganas de hacer nada y generalmente cabeceas. Te sientes imposibilitado para realizar o continuar con tus actividades, todo te da hueva… hasta pensar. Se te cierran los ojos, bostezos concurridos, irritabilidad y muchas ganas de “echarse un sueñito” por lo menos de 15 minutos.

Miremos también la imagen que lo acompaña:

[image]

Todo parece indicar que con esta expresión se genera una mímesis entre las formas del cerdo y las de una persona tras engullir gran cantidad de comida. Todos visualizamos al puerco tumbado (o *repanchingado*) en actitud de dejadez absoluta, digiriendo la comida y simplemente dejando el tiempo pasar hasta que el cuerpo se encuentre en condiciones para afrontar una tarea. Pues esa misma sensación puede atenazar el cuerpo de una persona después de una *comilona*, con su consiguiente pesadez de estómago y somnolencia.

Sobre su origen, se me ocurre la hipótesis de que alguien hablara del *mal de cuerpo* y otro, ingeniosamente, alterara el orden de las letras de *cuerpo* para dar con *puerco*. Una broma, en definitiva, para dar una imagen gráfica de un estado físico.

No he encontrado ninguna referencia "culta" al término. Esto es, no aparece ni en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) ni en el [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html).

---

<sub>Por cierto, la búsqueda de estos conceptos me ha deparado un grato descubrimiento del habla coloquial de México: ¡[godinez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/God%C3%ADnez_(subcultura_mexicana))! *(...) Utilizado para referirse a los oficinistas que habitualmente trabajan de 9:00AM a 6:00PM*.</sub>

Comment: Si, de echo por definición, o buscar a que se refiere o que es, no he tenido problema, más que nada es a cuando se empezó a usar

Comment: en realidad el uso de _godinez_ es mas para la gente que trabaja en horario de oficina y que entra muy justo y sale muy justo también, que espera la quincena como nadie al igual que los sábados, es como esa persona que trabaja porque tiene y no por que le guste su trabajo

Comment: @eezzekl tal y como indiqué en la respuesta, no he encontrado referencias ni en el CORDE ni en el CREA. El [Ngram de Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mal+de+puerco&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) tampoco ofrece resultados, por lo que no puedo decirte más que mis hipótesis sobre su origen. Tu comentario a Carlos Alejo diciendo que _por lo que he visto, la gente de edad avanzada es quien mas utiliza esta expresión, pero en general es de uso comun_ es lo más que tenemos pues :)

Comment: Yo alguna vez escuche a un profesor que el origen de la frase provenía del comportamiento de los cerdos, pero no tenía otro fundamento, ayer igual me puse a buscar sin éxito de encontrar una fuente confiable. Lo más cercano fue un [post en facebook de larousse latam](https://es-es.facebook.com/Larousselatam/posts/540320382670090)